# Add folders under generatedJava

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have a Gradle task that generates some source code files I would like to add under the generatedJava folder in Android Studio. Until now I only was able to add it under the source folder via Gradle.

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs+= 'build/generated/source/wsdl/'
    }
    ...
}
```

What do I need to set in the gradle build script so it will displayed under *generatedJava* like other generated classes for Android?

Comment: how do you generate these classes? using custom code or using some external library/framework ?

Comment: I have a greadle task that runs axis2 tool to generate the files which then are put under `build/generated/sources/wsdl/` under my project folder